# How to implement Single Sign On (SSO) in angular 2 apps with Azure AD B2B

Tags: angular, azure, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2b

I am building a portal that will group various angular 2 SPA apps. I need to sign in once in to the portal. After sign in all the angular 2 apps should work with signed in user context in new tabs.

I am using Angular 2 + Oauth 2 and Azure AD B2B.

How to share the user's context between two angular 2 apps.